# Login controller redirecting does not show page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a log in controller and a view. Whenever I click the log in button I check if the password given is correct and I used Redirect To Action to redirect to my home page. But, whenever I get to that page the page is not showing. What am I doing wrong???

In firebug it shows

```
GET http://localhost:64703/Home Page
```

should it be POST?

Javascript:

```
$('#Login').on('click', function () {
               var model = {};
                model["model.Password"] = $('#Password').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("Login", "LogIn")',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: model,
                        success: function (response) {
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                        }
                    });
            });
```

View:

```
<div >
        <div >
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                <table style="margin-top: 10px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <label id="errorMsg" class="calibri">
                            </label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="button" id="Login" value="Login" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Login(LogIn model)
            {
    try
                {
                    EntityConnection connection = connect.getConnection();
                    Entities ctx = new Models.Entities(connection);                 
                    connection.Open();
                    connection.Close();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "HomePage");

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {                   
                    return Json(ex);
                }
}
```

Here is my Code.. Please let me know what should be done and what should not be done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need more information to diagnose that. What is the page you are opening? Which routings are involved? Does it show up when you set a breakpoint in VS?

Comment: Also, what is the status code? Is it 200 OK or something else?

Comment: Hi Patrick, the page I'm trying to open is like my home page. I called it using return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); Also when I use breakpoint it enters that page but it's not showing. the status code is 200 OK.

Comment: Could you show your view and/or your `Action` code

Comment: `RedirectToAction()` causes the browser to make a `GET` request to the specified action. You do not need a `POST` in this case. If you update your question with some more code it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change only your jquery code, redirect the page:

```
success: function (response) {
   alert("if this test dialog appears, so page will redirect");

   //just add this line:
   window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "HomePage")';

},
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, on basis what you have posted, that there is either not a `Controller` or `Action` which matches:

- Controller: HomePage
- Action: Index

See the explanation of the [`RedirectToAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470594%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ajax to make the login request.

As such, you need to update your ajax response handlers to allow the page to redirect.

```
        $('#Login').on('click', function () {
           var model = {};
            model["model.Password"] = $('#Password').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Login", "LogIn")',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: model,
                    success: function (response) {
                         // Check for login is successful
                         if (response.LoginResult == true) window.location = response.Redirect;
                         else alert("Login failed.");
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                    }
                });
        });
```

// Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LogIn model)
{
    try
    {
        EntityConnection connection = connect.getConnection();
        Entities ctx = new Models.Entities(connection);
        connection.Open();
        connection.Close();
        if (true) // Logic to validate login
        {
            return Json(new { LoginResult = true, Redirect = RedirectToAction("Index", "HomePage") });
        }

        return Json(new { LoginResult = false });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(ex);
    }
}
```

The above sample fuzzies over the login logic - so use whatever logic you currently have.

The core concept is that the controller should return a json object that the client can evaluate and determine what to do.  Be aware that the success function will be triggered even if your login logic is incorrect - as long as there was no error by the server.

Comment: Do I have to change anything in my controller?

Comment: Thanks..I can now go through my homepage..
Here's the code:
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index","HomePage")";

But still I think there is something I am doing wrong. Thanks Kami. :)

Comment: @user3462803  Yes you will need to update your controller to send the correct values back. I have added some sample code. Not tested though.

Comment: I tried your code. But it says that "Window.Location is not a function" what library should I add?Thanks Kami.

Comment: @user3462803: You have to use `window.location = response.Redirect;`

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I tried to change it to window.location. But it says that the resource cannot be found.

Comment: @user3462803: Is the url in your browser correct? Maybe there is a second issue with your routing / controllers. See my answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I passed it like this -
return Json(new { LoginResult = true, Redirect = RedirectToAction("Index", "HomePage") });

Comment: @user3462803: I know, but is the URL correct? Are the controller and method there?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Yes. I can go to that page when the method I use to call it is different.

Comment: @user3462803 as you are using firebug, try adding `console.log(response);` to the success javascript function.  This should output the response object to the console, and you can see what the server is returning.  Also, where is the error "resource cannot be found" being generated? In the login controller, the Home controller or the javascript?

Comment: @Kami:  the Redirect was passed as an object. Reason why response.Redirect can't find the site that should be shown.I just used  what JhoonBey suggested. I just declare the url. Thank you very much Kami. :)

Comment: @user3462803 Given you controller implementation I am surprised that actually works, I would expect that code to redirect to home page even if the login details were invalid.

Comment: @Kami: sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to say. Your code works. But, window.location = response.Redirect; should be fixed because the server response for redirect is also an object that's why it cannot find the url. Thank you very much Kami.